# Display Data From Existing SQLite Database To Listview

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, listview

I am new to android programming so please help me…
I have created mydatabase.sqlite database file using SQLite Database Browser and copy it to assets folder in android application for retrieving data from the database file.

I want to display all the records from the database table on button click and display result in list view.

Here the code

this my databasehelper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{ 
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
//destination path (location) of our database on device 
private static String DB_PATH = "";  
private static String DB_NAME ="datacoba";// Database name 
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
private final Context mContext; 

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)  
{ 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version 
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; 
    this.mContext = context; 
}    

public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets 

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
    if(!mDataBaseExist) 
    { 
        this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        this.close(); 
        try  
        { 
            //Copy the database from assests 
            copyDataBase(); 
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
        }  
        catch (IOException mIOException)  
        { 
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
        } 
    } 
} 
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name 
    private boolean checkDataBase() 
    { 
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
        return dbFile.exists(); 
    } 

    //Copy the database from assets 
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
    { 
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int mLength; 
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
        { 
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
        } 
        mOutput.flush(); 
        mOutput.close(); 
        mInput.close(); 
    } 

    //Open the database, so we can query it 
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
    { 
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath); 
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS); 
        return mDataBase != null; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public synchronized void close()  
    { 
        if(mDataBase != null) 
            mDataBase.close(); 
        super.close(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 

}
```

this Utility Class

```
public class Utility {

    public static String GetColumnValue(Cursor cur, String ColumnName) {
        try {
            return cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ColumnName));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "";
        }
    }


    public static void ShowMessageBox(Context cont, String msg) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(cont, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        // toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

This Adapter Class

```
public class TestAdapter  
{ 
protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter"; 

private final Context mContext; 
private SQLiteDatabase mDb; 
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper; 

public TestAdapter(Context context)  
{ 
    this.mContext = context; 
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext); 
} 

public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException  
{ 
    try  
    { 
        mDbHelper.createDataBase(); 
    }  
    catch (IOException mIOException)  
    { 
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase"); 
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase"); 
    } 
    return this; 
} 

public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException  
{ 
    try  
    { 
        mDbHelper.openDataBase(); 
        mDbHelper.close(); 
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    }  
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
    { 
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
        throw mSQLException; 
    } 
    return this; 
} 

public void close()  
{ 
    mDbHelper.close(); 
} 

 public Cursor getTestData() 
 { 
     try 
     { 
         String sql ="SELECT Nama_student From Nama"; 

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
         if (mCur!=null) 
         { 
            mCur.moveToNext(); 
         } 
         return mCur; 
     } 
     catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
     { 
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
         throw mSQLException; 
     } 
 }
```

}

and this is my MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



public void LoadEmployee(View v)
{
    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);         
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
    mDbHelper.open(); 

    Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData(); 

    String name = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "Nama_student");


    Utility.ShowMessageBox(this, "Name: "+ name);
    mDbHelper.close();

}

}
```

The codes produces the output shown by toast, like [this](http://tinypic.com/r/1zm0cqw/8)
And just showed only the first row of the table. 
How can i display all rows from the table and show result in listview ?
EDIT: This my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:onClick="LoadEmployee"
        android:text="Load Employee"
       />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="166dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask Google first. Probably there is a bunch of tutorials for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see some `ListView` in your code. You need `ListView` and some adapter for it. Then, fill adapter with records from database and set this adapter to your `ListView`.

Why you return `Cursor` in your `getTestData` method? You can for example create some wrapper class and returns `List` with instances of this class. Via this `List` is very simple to create adapter for `ListView`.

Edit:

Ok, first you need to create an `ArrayAdapter`. You can use some other type of adapter, of course. Or you can create your custom adapter. This way is very simple.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

`List` is instance of some list, which contains data you want to display in `ListView`. Next, you simply initialize `ListView` and set the adapter.

```
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You can see above the line which creates an adapter. It is simple `ArrayAdapter`. But if you want to show single line in one `ListView` row, it is sufficient.

Comment: so i need this code in my databasehelper [link](http://tinypic.com/r/k2ph4/8) and set the return on  
 (context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, **set return on this field**); ?

Comment: it still have 1 problem, i already have context on databasehelper, now how can i initialized on main activity ?

can i initialized just like this  <br/>
Context mycontext;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mycontext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

Comment: If you are creating adapter in activity, just put `this` keyword into the first argument of constructor of `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the following code in your `LoadEmployee` method:

```
Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData();     

 /** the desired columns to be bound **/
 String[] columns = new String[] { "Nama_student" };

 /** the XML defined views which the data will be bound to **/
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };

 /** create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data as well as the layout information **/
 SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, columns, to);

 /** set this adapter as your ListActivity's adapter **/
 listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The following links will help you understand how it all works:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.tuicool.com/articles/rUFr2m